# Как убрать пробелы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть массив с цифрами без ковычек "13456 " "3532 " "3215 " "32132 " "5123 "
У меня не получается закинуть их в mysql таблицу в поле int() так как в конце имеются пробелы, пробелы пробую устранить следующим путем

```
str_replace(' ','',$price);
trim($price);
```

Не помогает, помогите.

в функцию вставляю конечно же не массив, а саму цифру

Comment:     $price=str_replace(' ','',$price);
    $price=trim($price);

Comment: так у меня так и стоит, я просто привел пример какие функции задействовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '"13456 " "3532 " "3215 " "32132 " "5123 "';
if( preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $match) ){
    // В массиве $match[0] все числа
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($match[0]);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
 $price = preg_replace("#\\s$#", "", $price);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intval();
floatval();
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте преобразование типов..

```
$price = (int)$price;
```

Answer (score 0):

$price = (int)$price; - приведи к нужному типу.